# ESP32-AsyncUDP own handler function for udp.onPacket

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

Can you please help me how to declare handler for udp.onPacket in the example below?

```
  if(udp.listen(1234)) {
        Serial.print("UDP Listening on IP: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
        udp.onPacket([](AsyncUDPPacket packet) {           
            Serial.print("UDP Packet Type: ");
            Serial.print(packet.isBroadcast()?"Broadcast":packet.isMulticast()?"Multicast":"Unicast");
            Serial.print(", From: ");
            Serial.print(packet.remoteIP());
            Serial.print(":");
            Serial.print(packet.remotePort());
        });
    }
```

I would like to have code like this

```
  if(udp.listen(1234)) {
        Serial.print("UDP Listening on IP: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
        udp.onPacket(processPacketHandler);
    }

  void processPacketHandler ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about binding functions in Arduino C++. I would try this:

```
    if(udp.listen(1234)) {
        Serial.print("UDP Listening on IP: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
        udp.onPacket([](AsyncUDPPacket packet) { processPacketHandler(packet); });
    }

    void processPacketHandler(AsyncUDPPacket packet){ ...
```